# How to enable php-debug in Atom?

Tags: php, atom-editor, xdebug

I have installed php-debug in Atom + its IDE dependencies. When I set a breakpoint the debug view opens saying *The debugger is not attached*, but when I am trying to do so it seems as if Atom doesn't recognize I have php-debug package installed and asks me to install a debugger.

I read on some places there is a toggle debugging setting on the package, but I can't see that option.

I'm using Atom `1.27.0` and PHP 7.2.4:

```
PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2018 02:49:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I could provide Xdebug configuration but seems like the problem is on Atom itself? Did anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple

1. Download xdebug from https://xdebug.org/download.php, TS version for Apache
2. Copy it to php/ext directory
3. Copy below text in php.ini below all other extensions

> zend_extension="D:/wamp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
>       [xdebug]
>       xdebug.remote_enable=1
>       xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
>       xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
>       xdebug.remote_port=9000
>       xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
>       xdebug.remote_mode=req
>       xdebug.remote_autostart=true

Restart Apache and Find "xdebug" string in `<?php phpinfo()?>`

- Install atom-debug_ui, php_debug
- Package > PHP Debug > Toggle
- Apply break-points and Run a PHP file from browser and that's it.

> If it ask for paths remote http://localhost/DIRECTORY_PATH_TO_PHP_FILE
>   and local is directory path to PHP file.

Comment: I guess xamp already have xdebug , you need check php.ini to see what port is assigned ... if xdebug setting not in php.ini then you can make above steps to integrate it xamp too, it will work there as well :)

Comment: Finaly made it with `php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15.dll`. I had xdebug 7.0 version and php 7.2. Works in VS Code too now

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same message few days ago …
Breakpoint were acually hit, I could see this because of the browser's tab loading icon, but nothing was happening on *Atom* user interface. All I could do was clicking stop or detach buttons which caused xdebug to end session and terminate browser tab load.
*Using PHP7.2.7, Xdebug 2.6 (Docker php-fpm-alpine); Atom 1.26.1 x64*

---

**TLDR;** *PHP-debug* extension couldn't process the "Path mappings" value I entered in the configuration panel.

---

Opening the dev console in *Atom* allowed me to spot an error accuring as the  debugging session gets initiated in PHP Debug extension.

```
Atom Debug (PHP Debug) Session initiated
logger.js? [sm]:43 Atom Debug (PHP Debug) [TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at Object.exports.generatePathMaps (/hom…]0: TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at Object.exports.generatePathMaps (/home/me/.atom/packages/php-debug/lib/helpers.js:80:34)
    at /home/me/.atom/packages/php-debug/lib/engines/dbgp/debugging-context.js:112:37
    …
```

This led me to read at the [Github repository](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/) and quickly figure what was going on.

All I had to do was changing the "Path mappings" text field value I erroneous filled in the first place. The text field expects a JSON string, as we can see [HERE](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/blob/931c4280f4e26e4df3bf2a3276b0d401e9774396/lib/helpers.js#L39), the path mappings should be an iterable/array made of objects. It has to loook like this:

```
[{"localPath":"/home/me/projects/my-project","remotePath":"/var/www/my-project"}]
```

Add more mapping objects if you have more than one project. Note that this setting is reflected in *~/.atom/.config.cson*

This fixed the issue, the debug view do not pop anymore saying there is no debugger attached.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the same error I have, I don't see that error on the console, also I believe I don't need path mappings as I'm running a local server

Comment: That's too bad this didn't help. So your Atom's dev console doen't expose any error and stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, with Atom 1.53.0, PHP 7.3, and XDebug 2.9.8. I could tell from netstat that XDebug was connecting to Atom, but there was no activity in the PHP Debug tab, and no messages in the Console or PHP Console to give a hint of what was (or wasn't) going on.

Unlike Stphane, I didn't have any path maps defined. But taking a hint from his answer, I clicked on the "Path Maps" button in the PHP Debug tab. Then a series of error dialogs popped up, which I was able to solve one at a time.

In my case, the errors all happened because the project I'd checked out had some Unix symlinks in it, which Windows didn't know how to interpret. I solved them by removing the symlinks, and copying into their place copies of the files and directories they'd been pointing to. After that, the PHP Debug pane worked as expected - although the Debugger still says "No debuggers installed".

Answer (score 0):

Atom Told me Debugger is not Attached but i made it work.

i saw atom php-debug tutorial but had problems like *debugger is not Attached*.

i want to share the configurations which that tutorial didn't includes:

### Xdebug.ini autostart and idekey

first in the tutorial xdebug config. configs it to run automatic.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

but its getting debugger run for every request. so you can make it off as this:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=false
```

after that you have to tell debugger to send debug to atom`s api by appending this to xdebug config:

```
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
```

if you use php-fpm, you have to reload it additional to restarting your http-server:

```
sudo systemctl reload php-fpm.service
```

### Browser Extension with correct idekey parameter

after that install the browser plugin which attach a cookie to tell xdebug to made this request debuggable.

if your plugin hasnt Atom config,

in your browser extention preferences make this:

```
IDE key: xdebug-atom
```

### Atom 2 plugins Enable and disable atom-ide-ui-feature-debug

and after that in Atom editor itself:

after installing **atom-debug-ui** and **php-debug** .

from Edit -> Preferences -> Package

select package **atom-ide-ui** package *settings*.

section **Enable Features** -> **Enable Debugger**

make it **Never enabled** .

like this:

https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/issues/310#issuecomment-419751273

### True Break Points

now from Packages -> Debug -> Toggle Debugger

another note is when you want to make break point in atom. there are 2 types of break point. **Big blue Dots** and **small blue dots**.

only small ones work for debugger.

like here suggested:
https://learnwithdaniel.com/2019/06/atom-php-debugger/

### Make remote path and local path identical

after setup request from browser. and Atom Asks you remote/local path.

make them identical